# An application to sniff a Bluetooth communication between a stethoscope and a computer

Tags: bluetooth

I have to access at sound record in a digital stethoscope.  But I don’t access directly to the record sound. I have to use a propriety application.
Someone knows software to sniff the Bluetooth transmission between the digital stethoscope and my computer. I need that to understand if I can program my application in Java to communicate with the stethoscope.

Thank you.

Best regards.

Daniel

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you please re-read your question and clean up the grammar / clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a Bluetooth sniffer , try [this](http://www.fte.com/products/fts4bt.aspx) http://www.fte.com/products/fts4bt.aspx